# C++ stream bitmask as bool?

Tags: c++, boolean, standards-compliance, bitmask

In the C++ standard, `std::ios::openmode`, `std::ios::fmtflags` and `std::ios::iostate` are implementation defined. But `std::ios::goodbit` is standardized to be equal to zero. My question is : can these bitmask be casted to boolean values according to the standard. In other words, to test if an error flag is set, can we type :

```
inline void myFunction(std::ios::iostate x = std::ios::goodbit) 
{
    if (x) { // <- is it ok or do I have to type "if (x != std::ios::goodbit)" ?
        /* SOMETHING */    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not portable code. [std::ios::iostate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) is a [Bitmask type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BitmaskType) which, according to the C++ standard (17.5.2.1.3):

> Each bitmask type can be implemented as an enumerated type that overloads certain operators, as an integer type, or as a bitset

If iostate is implemented in terms of the latter case, then your code will fail to compile as [std::bitset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) has neither an operator bool nor is it implicitly convertible to an integral type (as in your case).

Note:
The following fails to compile:

```
  std::bitset<8> b;
  return (b) ? 1 : 0;
```

while this works:

```
  std::bitset<8> b;
  return (b != 0) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: So the only portable way to do this is `x != std::iostate::goodbit` isn't it ?

Comment: @Vincent No. You can use the functions such as [`good`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good), [`bad`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/bad) and [`fail`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail).

Comment: @Vincent It may. I'm just answering your question that it isn't the *only* portable way.